# Why can't I connect my bluetooth speaker to my android tablet?

Tags: bluetooth-audio

I have an android tablet without bluetooth enabled ability. I also have an Ematic 8 in 1 bluetooth enabled speaker. I've tried several times to connect the speaker to the tablet using the audio 3.5 to 3.5 cable, but to no avail. It will not play the music. The music starts and plays, but no sound comes out. Can my device play through the speaker? And are all portable speakers bluetooth enabled? Thank you for any help you can give and I will await your response.

Comment: After you plugged-in the speaker cable to the phone, have you tried increasing the volume?

Comment: There may be a switch between Bluetooth, any other inputs and the 3.5mm jack. Ensure that is in the correct position if you wish to use auxiliary input. Check the instruction manual if there is one present on the function of the auxiliary port.

Answer (score 1):

Most Bluetooth speakers (not all) have a 3.5mm jack for the sole purpose of audio out, not audio in. Because of this, audio can not be sent to the Bluetooth speaker via auxiliary cable to be played, because the speaker's sole purpose is to output audio over a Bluetooth connection or through headphones in the speaker's 3.5mm jack.

My suggestion is to gain access to a device with Bluetooth and connect to the speaker to play music. Once this is done, connect headphones to the 3.5mm jack in  the speaker and see if the sound is played through the headphones, as opposed to sound coming directly from the speaker. If sound does play through the headphones, then you've found your solution.